# Create Child records for a parent record

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, versioning

I have a db table as given below:

| parentId | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |

I need to achieve CRUD operations to create child records so that sum of child record quantity should be max the parent quantity

| childId | quantity | parent id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | 1 |
| 2 | 35 | 1 |

Now here total of 60 quantities is created, now only 40 more quantities can be created. How can I acheive concurrency control such that no two transactions try to create it for different quantities and break the total quantity constraint. Is it possible via hibernate versioning.

I have tried to fetch all records, create a new record and save all records for creation.
And tried fetch all, update the selected and save all for updation considering all records versions will be incremented during this so that no parallel concurrent request and go in and break this consistency. But the issue here is while saving all, only the newly created or updated records version is incremented and found that hibernate only does that by default. Is there any hack to attain my requirement.